# Send an email html containing an image with webform in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I have a webform form that sends emails in html format with attachments.

For that, I use the modules **Mail System** and **Mime mail**. Everything works well.

For the body of the mail I use the option **Twig Template** and again everything works well ... except that I can not put an image (a logo) in the body.

I tried a lot of things and nothing works!

Every time I find myself with an empty  tag!

How to integrate the image of the logo into the body of my email?

Thanks for your help

Comment: For Drupal/Webform specific questions you should post to them to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webform

Answer (score 0):

I was able to include the Drupal logo without any problem using the below Twig template.

```
<img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon-small.png"/>
<hr/>
<p>Submitted on {{ webform_token('[webform_submission:created]', webform_submission) }}</p>
<p>Submitted by: {{ webform_token('[webform_submission:user]', webform_submission) }}</p>
<p>Submitted values are:</p>
{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values]', webform_submission) }}
```

The img tag is not stripped out. My only guess is the image's src is not using an absolute URL

Comment: Thank you Jacob for taking the time to answer me.
I understood why it did not work.
The problem comes from gmail. My test mails arrive in the spam box.
As a result, the images are not displayed.
But otherwise the images are displayed correctly.
Thank you very much